# print a column with the desire format output

Tags: awk, text-formatting, printf

I have a list of the following data in a file:

```
    -0.3476890000000000
    0.0743938333333333
    -1.0990240000000000
    0.0743938333333333
    -0.2169100000000000
    0.0879397500000000
```

and I am trying to align all data so to have:

```
    -0.347689000000000
    0.0743938333333333
    -1.099024000000000
    0.0743938333333333
    -0.216910000000000
    0.0879397500000000
```

unfortunately I couldn't make it with `awk '{printf "%18s\n", $1}'`. The ideal is to have an output like this:

```
   -0.3476890000000000
    0.0743938333333333
   -1.0990240000000000
    0.0743938333333333
   -0.2169100000000000
    0.0879397500000000
```

Comment: Your question says “I am trying to have *X*; the ideal is to have *Y*.”  What do you want?  Describe it in words.  Do you want the *strings* to be left aligned, so the **`-`** in front of negative numbers lines up with the first digit of non-negative numbers?  Do you want the numbers lined up on the **`.`**?  Do you want the strings to be right-aligned?  Do you want to truncate digits from the right?  Will you ever have an entry like `.142857` (with no leading zero)?  Will you ever have a number ≥ 10 (i.e., more than one digit)?

Comment: P.S. Every line of your sample file has 17 digits, where the rightmost 8 digits are the same.  This is very hard to read.  In the future, please present questions with data that can be looked at and understood.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe too small a field width. Try

```
awk '{printf "%19s\n", $1}' file
-0.3476890000000000
 0.0743938333333333
-1.0990240000000000
 0.0743938333333333
-0.2169100000000000
 0.0879397500000000
```

Answer (score 2):

Both GNU Awk (`gawk`) and `mawk` appear to support the C `printf` `' '` modifier that adds a space in front of positive numbers to align them with negative ones

> ```
>    ' '    (a  space)  A  blank should be left before a positive number (or
>           empty string) produced by a signed conversion.
> ```

So for example:

```
$ mawk '{printf "% 22.16f\n", $1}' file
   -0.3476890000000000
    0.0743938333333333
   -1.0990240000000000
    0.0743938333333333
   -0.2169100000000000
    0.0879397500000000
```

Alternatively, with `numfmt`

```
$ numfmt --format='% 22.16f' < file
   -0.3476890000000000
    0.0743938333333333
   -1.0990240000000000
    0.0743938333333333
   -0.2169100000000000
    0.0879397500000000
```

Comment: As far as I can tell, this is equivalent to `%22.16f` (without the space) except, with ``% 22.16f`` (with the space), numbers  ≥ 10000 will have an extra space added in front, so they line up with numbers  ≤ −10000, but not with numbers strictly between −10000 and 10000.  This might or might not be what the OP wants.

Answer (score 1):

you can also use `printf(1)`:

```
xargs <file printf '%19.16f\n'
-0.3476890000000000
 0.0743938333333333
-1.0990240000000000
 0.0743938333333333
-0.2169100000000000
 0.0879397500000000
```

or, if the input file isn't too big, the `printf` shell built-in:

```
undef IFS
printf '%19.16f\n' $(cat file)
```

Comment: Strictly speaking, if you're running it through ``xargs``, you aren't running the builtin.

Comment: @G-Man right, and that's not "simply speaking". It was "simply wrong"; xargs cannot run shell built-ins.